# how to deal with variable width of Buttons in ipywidgets

Tags: python, button, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

I have the need to display a bunch of buttons.
the description of every button corresponds to every word of a text.

In order to give a text appearance I want to make button width accoding to the length of the word inside.
So I create a variable that gives me the width px according to the number of letters.

I dont know why but it does not work well. It works for some words and for other doesnt.

some ideas?
(see in the screenshot how the word "the" does not have enough space in and only ... is dísplay.

The ultimate goal is of course have a text looking normally as a text where I can click words.

Thanks.

```
mylist=['loren','ipsum','whapmmtever','loren','ipsum','otra','the','palabra','concept']

list_btns=[]
for i,word in enumerate(mylist):
    # here I try to define the width of the button as depending on the length of the word:
    wordwidth= str(len(word)*12) + 'px'
    wd_raw_save_button = widgets.Button(description=word,
                                        disabled=False,
                                        button_style='success',
                                        tooltip='check the word',
                                        icon='',
                                        layout = Layout(width = wordwidth, margin='0px 0px 0px 0px'))

    list_btns.append(wd_raw_save_button)



showcase=HBox(list_btns)
showcase
```

[image: how it looks like in jupyter]

Actually after running voila to visualise the result I get this:

[image]

this does not give an impression of real text, i.e. same spacing between words which is the ultimate goal. 
I am guessing, but I am not sure, that the reason might be that the characters are of different width, and I will have to calculate the width character by character. But this does not explain that the word "the" does not fit inside the button.
Second explanation is that the underlying CSS assumes a certain minimum border which goes "over" the word itself. In any case I dont know how to control/influence it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's limited control for the CSS for widgets. There seems to be a cutoff around 40px where text will get truncated. I used a simple `max` comparison to get hopefully close to what you are looking for:

```py
from ipywidgets import *
mylist=['loren','ipsum','whapmmtever','loren','ipsum','otra','the','palabra','concept', 'a'] * 2

list_btns=[]
for i,word in enumerate(mylist):
    # here I try to define the width of the button as depending on the length of the word:
    wordwidth= max(len(word) * 12, 40)
    wordwidth = str(wordwidth) + 'px'
    wd_raw_save_button = widgets.Button(description=word,
                                        disabled=False,
                                        button_style='success',
                                        tooltip='check the word',
                                        icon='',
                                        layout = Layout(width = wordwidth, margin='0px 0px 0px 0px')
                                       )

    list_btns.append(wd_raw_save_button)



showcase=HBox(list_btns, layout= Layout(width='100%'))
showcase
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @ac24 thanks for your answer. we are closer. not yet there (perhaps its impossible). Imagine that the change the green color to white and the font letter to black. the spaces between the words will not yet give a normal appearance to the text. But at least with your proposal all the words can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```py
display(ipywidgets.HTML("<style>.narrow_button { padding: 0px 2px; border: 1px solid black  }</style>"))
```

**Pay attention that this line is inside the exact same cell where you display the ipywidgets.** The second line of code that is needed, comes after you defined your ipywidget. Now you have to assign this styling to each widget. Inside the loop, use:

```py
wd_raw_save_button.add_class('narrow_button')
```

Then my buttons look like this: [image]

Produced by your modified example:

```py
from ipywidgets import *
import ipywidgets
mylist=['loren','ipsum','whapmmtever','loren','ipsum','otra','the','palabra','concept']
display(ipywidgets.HTML("<style>.narrow_button { padding: 0px 2px; border: 1px solid black  }</style>"))
list_btns=[]
for i,word in enumerate(mylist):
    # here I try to define the width of the button as depending on the length of the word:
    wordwidth= str(len(word)*12) + 'px'
    wd_raw_save_button = widgets.Button(description=word,
                                        disabled=False,
                                        button_style='success',
                                        tooltip='check the word',
                                        icon='',
                                        layout = Layout(width = 'auto', margin='0px 0px 0px 0px'))
    wd_raw_save_button.add_class("narrow_button")
    list_btns.append(wd_raw_save_button)



showcase=HBox(list_btns)
showcase
```